# Which version of HDP should I use to work with Mahout 0.9 and Hadoop 1.x

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, mahout, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to use Mahout 0.9 for a project. It is said that Mahout 0.9 works well with hadoop 1.x, and there are some problems with hadoop 2.x compatibility. Therfore I need to have Mahout 0.9 and hadoop 1.x. By default HDP 1.3.3 has Mahout 0.7 according to the sources. Can I upgrade Mahout to 0.9 after I install HDP 1.3.3?

If Mahout 0.9 works well with hadoop 2.x, then there is no problem. But can someone assure that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last release of HortonWorks DataPlatform (2.1) of April 2014 Mahout 0.9 is supported. I used mahout 0.9 with Hadoop 2.3 and I didn't have any problem so i guess there is no reason to not use it.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it, for sure. No problem.